# Access a variable from a script in another script

Tags: c#

First of all I want to make clear the fact that I'm not using Unity or anything related to this .

I want to get values from a variable from a script to another , but inside the same .cs file.

My variable is named spellpos

Im setting it's values in this script

```
     public class MyMissile: ISpellScript
etc etc

      public void CastKeg(ISpellMissile missile)
        { etc
            var spellpos = new Vector2(daspell.CastInfo.TargetPositionEnd.X, daspell.CastInfo.TargetPositionEnd.Z);
   etc 

        } etc etc
```

Then I want to access that spellpos value in another script

```
    public class GragasQToggle : ISpellScript
etc etc 

        public void OnSpellCast(ISpell spell)
        {
            var position = spellpos;

        }
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Try reading about access modifiers: [Acess Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Comment: *from a script in another script* - Do you mean accessing a field in one class from another class?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing It was stated in the first sentence that Is not made using unity , just pure , raw C# .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your variable public:

```
public class MyMissile: ISpellScript
{
    public static Vector2 spellpos;

    public void CastKeg(ISpellMissile missile)
    { 
        spellpos = new Vector2(daspell.CastInfo.TargetPositionEnd.X, daspell.CastInfo.TargetPositionEnd.Z);
    }
}
```

And now you can access the variable from the other class:

```
public class GragasQToggle : ISpellScript
{
    public void OnSpellCast(ISpell spell)
    {
        var position = MyMissile.spellpos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OR
You can make the first method return the value and use in the second method like below:

```
public Vector2 CastKeg(ISpellMissile missile)
{ 
        var spellpos = new Vector2(daspell.CastInfo.TargetPositionEnd.X, daspell.CastInfo.TargetPositionEnd.Z);

        return spellpos;
}
```

And then you call in the second method like below:

```
    public void OnSpellCast(ISpell spell)
    {
        var position = CastKeg(spell);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make get and set functions for each class
and leave them as private.

If those are separated programs or even the same program a creative solution is to use TCP sockets.